# Grease-Pencil - SVG export Stroke Depth Order

Tags: grease-pencil, svg

When I export my grease pencil as SVG and open it in Vector Software, the Stroke Depth Order for Fill color is gone...
So I'm missing something or it just not implemented ?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a short answer, you’re missing ... a whole lot.

Joking aside, your main issue stems from your understanding of how you are supposed to use the grease pencil fill feature and thus you lack an understanding of the whole grease pencil object altogether. There are two main problems that I can outline in your file, one if you accept my previous statement.

**Problem 1: Understanding Grease Pencil Objects**

Although blender treats grease pencil objects as 3d objects, that doesn’t mean users of blender use them as 3d objects all the time. Grease pencil was originally an annotation tool that evolved into blender’s main 2D illustration feature.

[image]

There is not a single tutorial about blender’s grease pencil that I have seen that does not mention that the fill feature (fill tool, fill stroke, etc.) is a 2D aspect that CANNOT be used in 3D space.

This is how I concluded that you don’t know how to work with grease pencil objects because you expect the fills to behave like mesh planes even though they do not. Blender treats grease pencil objects as curves and curves conflict with meshes which leads us to your second problem.

**Problem 2: 3D Modeling vs. 2D Illustration**

In your case, I’m guessing that you took your mesh objects and simply converted them into grease pencil objects through one of the methods below.

*Mesh $\rightarrow$ grease pencil*

*Mesh $\rightarrow$ curve $\rightarrow$ grease pencil*

Although I don't want to say that converting is incorrect, it is however, aesthetically rigid, impractical, and plagued with technical problems.

Whether you realized this or not, you are trying to 3D model an illustration. Although Blender promotes drawing in 3D, there are very, very, VERY specific methods on how to do so circulating around the community. These methods consist of drawing over your 3d models, using 3d models within your drawings, and incorporating 3d modeling into your drawings.

**Solution for Problem 1: Reprojection**

Here is the direct solution.

The line art modifier has implicitly become the main tool to connect grease pencil objects to mesh objects.

[image]

Once you apply the modifier, go to *Edit mode $\rightarrow$ Select all strokes $\rightarrow$ Grease Pencil $\rightarrow$ Clean Up $\rightarrow$ Reproject Strokes $\rightarrow$ View (to reproject your grease pencil to the camera’s 2d view).*

[image]

You can then use the fill feature of grease pencil.

[image]

Export grease pencil object to a svg file.

[image]

**Solution for Problem 2: Non-Photorealistic Rendering**

Here is the indirect solution.

Although the line art modifier has already solved problem 2, we can do away with grease pencil objects all together and just use meshes as is.

Turn on the Render: Freestyle SVG Exporter add-on.

[image]

Go to *Render Properties $\rightarrow$ CHECK Freestyle AND CHECK Freestyle SVG Export (to export as svg) $\rightarrow$ CHECK Fill Contours (to export with colors)*

[image]

Now go to *View Layers $\rightarrow$ CHECK Export Fills*

[image]

Change colors in *Material Properties $\rightarrow$ Viewport Display $\rightarrow$ Color*

[image]

Hit Render. Your svg file is in the folder from where you have your renders saved (tmp folder for me)

[image]

I opened the svg files inside GIMP since I do not have a vector graphics program installed on my machine.

[image]
*Blender 4.0.2*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have try to reproduce the same with no success…

I have do this :

Add →  Grease Pencil →  Collection line Art

Edit mode → Select all

But nothing is selected… it’s always in 3D and I don’t understand how to transform I in 2D …
And I don’t understand how do you fill the cube color ?

Comment: Did you apply the Line Art modifier? No lines exist in the grease pencil object if you don't apply it.

Comment: To apply modifiers, there is a drop-down menu to the right of the name of the modifier and directly left of the X delete button. The apply button is within the drop-down menu. You'll know the modifier is applied when it disappears.

Comment: I filled the cube color using the materials you already made in grease pencil with the fill tool. To use the fill tool, you have to switch the grease pencil object's mode to Draw mode.

Comment: thanks. I didn't apply the modifier so I have now my 2D shape, but always have some troubles to fill more complexe shape. 
I have created another Question about that here : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310731/grease-pencil-create-square-closed-line-per-face-quad

Comment: np, . If my solution has answered your question, please help me by marking it as correct.