# GREASE PENCIL - Create square closed line per face (Quad)

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

I have add -> Grease Pencil -> Collection line Art
Is it possible to force the creation of the line to be a closed square for each face on a quad mesh ?

Instead to have line connected in chaos way …

I'm trying to get a clean SVG file.
And for that I need closed line art for each face of my mesh.

So that after that, I can select all the grease pencil shapes to fill them properly. So if my shape is a cube, in the camera view I'll have 3 grease pencil shapes with 4 points each....

Thanks !

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can tell that you are unfamiliar with grease pencil and English is most likely not your first language but, that doesn't make this question any less undescriptive. Your goal is convoluted, and I am having trouble understanding what it is that you want to accomplish.

Comment: If you are trying to draw closed lines over the quad faces of your mesh, then you have already done so in the blend file you provided because those two meshes are modeled simply. However, if you are trying to generate more lines over the faces of your mesh then this question becomes a `Modeling` or `Topology` question. The line art modifier only generates lines from existing edges and faces of your meshes.

Comment: If this is truly a question about generating line art with the line art modifier, then your answer can be inferred from the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modifiers/generate/line_art.html).

Comment: THANK YOU for the kind words :)
I'm trying to get a clean SVG file.

And for that I need closed line art for each face of my mesh.
So that after that, I can select all the grease pencil shapes to fill them properly.
So if my shape is a cube, in the camera view I'll have 3 grease pencil shapes with 4 points each....

Comment: I suggest you change your question to the comment you just made because your comment was more descriptive then your question. 

Answer (score 1):

I am answering your comment instead of your question since it is more accurate to what you want to achieve. You are trying to create closed line art for independent shapes within your mesh.

Although this can be accomplished in several ways, since you tagged this question with `grease-pencil` and `lineart`, I'll answer your question with only those two in mind. I suggest using the `Fill` tool as a quick fix.

In your file, you already have an applied line art grease pencil object. I reprojected it in order to show you how to use the `Fill` tool.

[image]

Every fill made by the fill tool has its own stroke boundary whose thickness can be changed like any other stroke.

[image]

If you just want the boundaries of your independent shapes or quads then switch the material to `Stroke` instead of `Fill` that you use for the fill tool.

If you export all your fills with the same line thickness as your line art then you can fundamentally have your independent closed shapes. As a note, fill tool can only fill closed strokes so, the fills we made using the fill tool should already have closed boundaries. Whether you think it is clean or not is up for interpretation.

Comment: Each time I try to use the fill tool it said : Unable to fill unclosed area…
I can only use file tool in a new 2D animation workspace…
What I need to do before to fill the shape correctly ?

Comment: Friend, you are descending into a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Blender Stack Exchange is a question-and-answer website designed to further the use of Blender and its community. I know the struggle is real for you with your language barrier but, this site is not here to personally teach you how to use Blender.

Comment: As for your issue, I don't know what version of Blender you are using or how you have your settings set so, I can't give you a clear response. Please read more about the fill tool, [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modes/draw/tools/fill.html#boundary-strokes).

Comment: Hello,Obfuscate, I read your comments here as being a completely genuine effort to help @BLenjamin. However, they are open to misinterpretation.. so,  if in this case, you could confine yourself strictly to the problem at hand .. (alternative solutions, open requests for clarification without expressed judgement) that would help us along. If you've done all you can, let it be. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, Robin. My comments were out of context and were too insulting. I apologize to [BLenjamin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/147680/blenjamin) and anyone else who felt I was unhelpful. I will try to do better next time.